# error C2143 and error C2059 about changing a variable into a subroutine

Tags: c, syntax-error

I tried to search on the Web, but I found nothing..
So I post the relevant code:

```
typedef struct wind {
    float xlat;
    float ylong;
    float zheight;
    float mod;
    float elev;
    float az;} wind_dat;


static void   dataprocess( const char *, wind_dat& , int& ); // Errors C2143 and C2059

int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {   
   int num;
   char   *filename    = "Data/wind_data.txt";
   wind_dat *dat;
   dataprocess(filename, dat, num);
   .../*many boring operation*/
   }

static void dataprocess (const char *filename, wind_dat& dat, int& num) // Errors C2143 and C2059
{
int it;
float coord[3], obs_cart[3], a[3][3];

FILE *ptrfile;

if ((ptrfile=fopen(filename, "r"))==0)
{printf("\nError in opening file.\n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
fscanf(ptrfile,"%d",&num);
if ((dat=(wind_dat *)malloc(num*sizeof(wind_dat)))==NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

pol2cart(obs_cart,obs[0],obs[1],obs[2]+6371000);
a[0][0]=cos(az)*cos(obs[1]+PI)+sin(az)*sin(PI+obs[1])*cos(PI-obs[0]);
a[0][1]=cos(az)*sin(obs[1]+PI)-sin(az)*cos(obs[1]+PI)*cos(PI-obs[0]);
a[0][2]=-sin(az)*sin(PI-obs[0]);
a[1][0]=sin(az)*cos(obs[1]+PI)-cos(az)*sin(obs[1]+PI)*cos(PI-obs[0]);
a[1][1]=sin(az)*sin(obs[1]+PI)+cos(az)*cos(obs[1]+PI)*cos(PI-obs[0]);
a[1][2]=cos(az)*sin(PI-obs[0]);
a[2][0]=sin(obs[1]+PI)*sin(PI-obs[0]);
a[2][1]=-sin(PI-obs[0])*cos(obs[1]+PI);
a[2][2]=cos(PI-obs[0]);
for (it=0;it<num;it++)
    {fscanf(ptrfile,"%f %f %f %f %f %f",&dat[it].xlat, &dat[it].ylong, &dat[it].zheight, &dat[it].mod, &dat[it].elev, &dat[it].az);
    pol2cart(coord, dat[it].xlat, dat[it].ylong, dat[it].zheight+6371000);
    coord[0]=coord[0]-obs_cart[0];
    coord[1]=coord[1]-obs_cart[1];
    coord[2]=coord[2]-obs_cart[2];
    dat[it].xlat =  coord[0]*a[0][0]+coord[1]*a[0][1]+coord[2]*a[0][2];
    dat[it].ylong = coord[0]*a[1][0]+coord[1]*a[1][1]+coord[2]*a[1][2];
    dat[it].zheight=coord[0]*a[2][0]+coord[1]*a[2][1]+coord[2]*a[2][2];
    dat[it].az=dat[it].az-az/PI*180;
    }
fclose(ptrfile);
}
```

This are the error message after I try to compile in the two rows where dataprocess is declared and where there is the body of the function:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '&'
error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '&'
error C2059: syntax error : '&'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

If there is something not clear at all I'll edit for you.

PS: Excuse me for my bad English..

EDIT: I wrote where errors are like the suggestion
I'm using VC++ 2008 and on the Web I found that this error is caused by using C compiler, but in my case it's C++ compiler, so I just don't understand what I miss..

Comment: Is this about C or C++? The former wouldn't work.

Comment: How do you suppose people can tell where lines 2143 and 2059 are? Point out those lines in the code by adding // <-- line XXX comments in those 2 places (not on every line of course)

Comment: also, what did you search for on the web? and which compiler are you using, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void   dataprocess( const char *, wind_dat& , int& );
```

'type & var' syntax is for C++ only, references are nonexistent in C. Use pointers instead.

Comment: I was about to say this.  I'll add that the code as C++ is incorrect as well in that a `wind_dat *` is passed in, while the function is expecting a `wind_dat` argument that it'll treat as a reference.

Comment: I don't know, maybe because I build the ARToolkit and VC++ in two different folder in my PC..because now I tried to paste only the relevant code without the function of GLUT and ARToolkit and it 's working..Is it possible?

Comment: @jack_aerospace VC++, despite the name, is both a C and a C++ compiler. The most likely reason I can think of for this code to compile in one file but not another is if one file is being compiled as C++ (which should work) and the other as C (which should fail).  

IIRC by default files with the extension .c are compiled as C, those with .cpp as C++. I'm pretty sure you can also force one or the other with compiler options.

Comment: yes, it was a c file, but when I create a .cpp file and copied the code in the new file, the error message was the same..I can't understand the matter..help!!